# Object-oriented design - pause function

Tags: java, oop

I was trying to sharp my OOD thinking. Here is my question.

Suppose you want to design a music mp3 player. And I got a class with a collection of playlists.

```
class Player {
    Map<String, List<Song>> playlists;    // <Name, PlayList>
    public void play (Song song) {
        // decode song
        // play song
    }
    public void play (String playlistName) {
        // play a playlist
        for (Song song : playlists.get(playlistName)) {
            play (song);
        }
    }
    public void stop () {
        // stop playing
    }
    public void pause () {
        // pause, resume playing the last song when hit play again
    }
}
```

Let's assume "Song" already contains all the metadata of a song. All the functionalities of methods have been described. I got stucked when I was trying to realize the "pause" method. What would you do to realize this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). Which you will store state of the player. When you hit pause and play you will know the state of the player.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a `Song` member variable that tracks the currently playing song. If there is nothing playing, the value would be set to null. When you pause a `Song`, you simply call the `Pause` method on the `Song` class if the currently playing `Song` is not null. The `Song` class in turn can track where in the song (in terms of minutes) it is and figure out how a resume would work.

Comment: It also needs to interrupt the play() method/s that might be running - that requires a bit of synchronization though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like th play method blocks until the song has finished. It is a completely single-threaded design. When you design your application like that, it can't react to user input while a song is playing (unless you place an input handler into the playing loop).

In a real-world application, the play() method would start playing the song in a separate thread (many audio APIs will do that for you, so that you don't have to mingle with multi-threading) and then return, so that the application can stay responsible while a song is playing.

That way the pause and resume methods would then interact with the thread which plays the song.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you are saying. Just for curiosity, how these audio APIs actually respond to a pause operation? They just kill the thread that is playing the music?